# all files appear be checked out .. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I just opened my visual studio 2005 solution file with multiple projects and all the files in the solution appear to be checked out. Every file in this solution has "check-mark" next to it. I DONOT want to check out the file and accidentally check it in.

In solution file, there are over 70 projects. Each project close to 20 files.

Please help.

thanks

Comment: What source control system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you undo checkout?  Perhaps from Source Safe instead of Visual Studio?

Comment: I have over 70 projects. Each project close to 20 files. I am hoping for a much simpler solution.

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner - Why can't you do this on the top level solution/directory?